# 3D Cube scrolling on hover, working on tablets

Tags: ipad, html, css, 3d, cube

The only thing I want to know is if this is possible,
I want an 3d cube that scrolls(horizontally) if you move with your finger at the tablet screen. I want to use HTML5 + CSS3 For this, I am just not sure if this is possible.

Needs to work on iPads, iPhones, Galaxy tabs, etcetra.

I apprentice ur help if you you any more about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're asking whether if this is possible or not, the answer is ***yes***, it can be done.
Here's a demo that can at least point you to the right direction : http://www.paulrhayes.com/experiments/cube-3d/touch.html